# Registering pressed keys with TextInputEditText in Android

Tags: android, keylistener, keyevent

I'm trying to capture which key is pressed on a TextInputEditText (from Material Design) and although I press any key from keyboard I can't manage to go into onKey method. Could someone help me ?

```
txtInputApo.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.i("onKey","true");
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
                switch (keyCode){
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE:
                        String Espaces = txtInputApo.getText().toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
                        txtInputApo.setText(Espaces);
                        txtInputApo.setSelection(Espaces.length());
                        break;

                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`View.OnKeyListener` was mainly built for hardware input in mind. Most of the time it's better to utilize a `TextWatcher` instead for this kind of scenario (monitoring and modifying user input).

You can do something like this to achieve your desired result with a `TextWatcher`:

```
    TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String editableString = s.toString();
            if (editableString.contains(" ")) {
                final String spaceFreeString = editableString.replaceAll(" ", "");
                txtInputApo.setText(spaceFreeString);
                txtInputApo.setSelection(spaceFreeString.length());
            }
        }
    };
    txtInputApo.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried with `TextWatcher` before, but I also have to capture enter key and I didn't know how to do it. Anyway I think I can manage with this solution. Thank you!